# Why is Sri Krishna not worshipped as father?

Tags: shiva, krishna, worship

Lord Krishna is generally not worshipped as 'father'.He is worshippd as 'friend', 'master', 'lover', 'child' etc. Lord Shiva on the other hand, is worshipped mainly as father.

Sri Krishna told in Gita that He is the father of the world. Lord Shiva is known as the destroyer of the world often.

So why is Shiva worshipped as 'father' while Krishna is never?

I believe that both are the forms of the same Para-Brahman by the way and do not treat any of them as superior or inferior to the other.

Comment: Krishna is avatar of Parabrahman and Krishna is Non different from Isvara. Lord Shiva is not destroyer but he is the Param jyoti! Destroyer is Rudra!

Comment: Yes, i used the word 'often' for that. But the basic Q remains! @AkshayS

Comment: Well in general a father is supposed to be strong, masculine, strict, non-emotional, angry at times hence in a way portrays image that of Shiva, where as Krishna is more of a lover, a Casanova, very emotional, easy going ..... traits not usually related with most fathers. @commonman

Comment: You can worship him as father.Krishna is not worshiped as father because he's character in mahabharata and other epics is like friend and master.And shivas character is that of father in shivas epics.So what people know they will worship that style.It doesn't matter how you worship them as but as you worship them they will be behave like your father,brother etc.Example tulsi and radha worshiped him as lover.Arjun as friend.Whatever you worship you become the same.Example prahlada found god every where and god use to appear everywhere like pillar.....

Comment: @PravinRGMishra The number of children and wives of Lord Krisnna are much higher than those of Lord Shiva as per the scriptures.

Comment: @commonman yaa but scriptures mention much more stories about his friendship then his fatherwood.

Comment: When it comes to Parabrahman, there's no masculine and feminine. So we cant relate with our qualities of emotions, angry etc.. to Parabrahman. He is both the father as well as mother of this entire Cosmic manifestation. Krishna also can be worshipped as father of this Universe as he is "Jagad Guru, Jagad Isvara". Krishna is all round because he in one phase enjoys love with Gopis, and in other place he delivers Bhagavad Gita in a war. We cant restrict Krishna with just particular phase because he has all qualities, and he knows how to be in particular situation,.

Comment: Even if you take sanyasa, Krishna accepts you. Even if you be Karma Yogi, he accepts you. Even if you are Bhakti like Meera, he accepts you. Krishna is Universal master!!! So both can be worshipped but due to certain limited understanding of human mind, we have not worshipped him like that!.

Comment: What is the meaning of "worshipping as a father"? @commonman

Comment: @Rickross Sakhabhava, Madhurabhava etc are applied but NOT pitribhava:)